# Search, disable and move computer account

Tags: vbscript, active-directory

I am trying to build a script which seaches for a computer item, disables and moves it to another AD OU. Running it as administrator works but I have to add a variable for user credentials and this will actually work :(.

```
Const ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE = 2

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objCommand    = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

objConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
objConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
Set objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection
objCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 1000
objCommand.Properties("Searchscope") = ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE
objConnection.Properties("User ID") = "user"         'pass credentials - if you omit this, the search is performed...
objConnection.Properties("Password") = "pass"        '... with the current credentials
objConnection.Properties("Encrypt Password") = True  'only needed if you set "User ID" and "Password"
objCommand.CommandText = "SELECT ADsPath FROM 'LDAP://dc=something,dc=com' WHERE objectCategory='computer' AND name='"& strComputer &"'"

Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute

objRecordSet.MoveFirst
Do Until objRecordSet.EOF
  strADsPath = objRecordSet.Fields("ADsPath").Value
  Set objComputer = GetObject(strADsPath)
  objComputer.AccountDisabled = True
  objComputer.SetInfo
  Set objOU = GetObject("LDAP://OU=HARDWARE,OU=Deleted Items,DC=something,DC=com")
  Set objReturn = objOU.MoveHere(strADsPath, vbNullString)
  objRecordSet.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: So, what doesn't work as expected?

Comment: Are you putting `"domain\user"` in the `"User ID"` field? https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2005/12/09/how-can-i-use-alternate-credentials-when-searching-active-directory/